# How to use insert() in a for loop without making it a endless loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to make a project in python so that whenever the program encounters a capital letter it makes a white space. So for example "helloThisIsMyProject" > hello This is My Project.

```
def project(w):
    lst = []
    for i in w:
        lst.append(i)
    for letter in lst:
        if letter.isupper():
           index = lst.index(letter)
           lst.insert(index, " ")
           continue
    return "".join(lst)

print(project("helloThisIsMyProject"))
```

I'm having a problem with insert() and the for loop because the for loop is endlessly looping over the "T" from "This". I tried using continue to skip the letter T but it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: You should never modify a list that you are currently iterating. Make a function that creates and returns a *new* list or string.

Comment: a simple modification without refactoring your code a lot, would be to replace: `lst.insert(index, " ")` with `lst[index] =  " " + lst[index]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those 1st three lines are simply

```
lst = list(w)
```

But you would find this more convenient:

```
lst = []
for letter in w:
    if letter.isupper():
        lst.append(" ")
    lst.append(letter)
```

That is, rather than producing a list and going back to fix it up,
you could have it correct from the outset.
You can conditionally output a SPACE before you output the letter.

---

If you prefer to do it with a list comprehension,
you might enlist the aid of a helper:

```
def adjust(s: str) -> str:
    """Returns the input string, possibly whitespace adjusted."""
    return " " + s if s.isupper() else s

lst = [adjust(letter)
       for letter in w]
```

or more compactly:

```
lst = list(map(adjust, w))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join with a list comprehension that adds the space to individual characters:

```
def spaceCaps(w):
    return "".join(" "*c.isupper()+c for c in w)

spaceCaps("helloThisIsMyProject")

'hello This Is My Project'
```

You could also use the sub() function from the regular expression module:

```
import re

def spaceCaps(w):
    return re.sub("([A-Z])",r" \1",w)
```